# Import Module into another module to access services

Tags: angular, import

I have the following `module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivitiesService } from '../services/activities.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [ActivitiesService],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [],
    exports: [ActivitiesService]
})

export class ActivitiesModule { }
```

The `ActivitiesService` will be used through different components within my application, so I decided to create a shared module for the `ActivitiesService` which imports the service and exports it making it available for other modules to import.

I then created a new `module`, this module will import the above `module` which is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Components
import { ProfileComponent } from '../component/profile/profile.component';

// Routing
import { profileRouting } from '../routing/profile-routing';

// Shared << IMPORTED OTHER MODULE HERE
import { ActivitiesModule } from '../../shared/modules/activities.module';


import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Authentication Guard
import { AuthenticationGuard } from '../../shared/guards/authentication.guard';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        profileRouting,
        FormsModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ActivitiesModule],
    declarations: [
        ProfileComponent],
    providers: [AuthenticationGuard]
})

export class ProfileModule { }
```

Now inside my `ProfileComponent` I have the following declaration:

```
// Services
import { ActivitiesService } from '../../../shared/services/activities.service';
```

The constructor for `ProfileComponent`

```
constructor(private activityService: ActivitiesService) {}
```

My `ngOnInit` method looks like so:

```
ngOnInit() {

   this.activityService.getActivities();

}
```

Yet when I run this, and navigate to the `Profile` page I get the error message:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value
>   'ActivitiesService' imported by the module 'ActivitiesModule'. Please
>   add a @NgModule annotation. Error: Unexpected value
>   'ActivitiesService' imported by the module 'ActivitiesModule'. Please
>   add a @NgModule annotation.

I've checked naming conventions, checked @NgModule annotation and it's all correct.  Can someone shed some light into what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by doing the following:

`ActivitiesModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivitiesService } from '../services/activities.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [],
    providers: [ActivitiesService],
    bootstrap: [],
    exports: []
})

export class ActivitiesModule { }
```

Importing into the `ProfileModule` remains the same.